# RMI client with another port

Tags: client-server, port, rmi

I've really searched hours and hours but I didn't find any solutions. I want that my client on a VM (Windows server 2008) get in communication with my host (main system: windows 7).

```
public class TestClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException
    {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("13.211.124.80",TestRemote.RMI_PORT);
        TestRemote remote = (TestRemote) registry.lookup(TestRemote.RMI_ID);
        System.out.println(remote.isLoginValid("tst"));
        System.out.println(remote.isLoginValid("test"));
        System.out.println(TestRemote.RMI_PORT);
    }
}
```

IP from host: `13.211.124.80`

RMI Server class

```
public class RMIServer
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException
    {
        RemoteImpl impl = new RemoteImpl();
        Registry registry=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(TestRemote.RMI_PORT);
        registry.bind(TestRemote.RMI_ID, impl);
        System.out.println("server is started");
    }
}
```

Impl Class:

```
public class RemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements TestRemote
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    protected RemoteImpl() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

    public boolean isLoginValid(String username) throws RemoteException
    {
        if (username.equals("test"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Interface class:

```
public interface TestRemote extends Remote
{
    public boolean isLoginValid(String username) throws RemoteException;
    public static final String RMI_ID = "TestRMI";
    public static final int RMI_PORT = 888;
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.interf.test.TestRemote (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is perfectly clear. Whatever component threw that exception does not have that class on its CLASSPATH. It could have been the Registry or the client, depending on the stack trace, which you didn't post completely.